# how can you hold unwind segue between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

When implementing unwind segue, I've done it just by tapping back button on navigation controller. But how can I do that by swiping left on VC?

Not only that, in the apps like Facebook, Twitter and Instagram, you can hold the VC when performing unwind segue. How can it be possible?

**I want to implement this programmatically in Swift**

Thanks for your advice!

[image: Twitter example]

Comment: that is a built-in functionality that is always present when using navigation controllers with displayed navigation bar. Apart from that you can create custom transitions and interactive transitions that let you react to the user interaction and perform awesome animations.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. My actual question was how can I hold VC when user pressing the VC while unwind segue is happening. I have no idea how can I do that like Twitter.